# Cannot set input volume of MultiChanelMixer AudioUnit bus

Tags: core-audio, midi, audiotoolbox, coremidi

I am trying to use CoreAudio/AudioToolbox to play multiple MIDI files using different MIDISynth nodes. I have the samplers wired into a MultiChanelMixer which is in turn wired into the IO unit. I want to be able to change the different input volumes independently of one another. I'm attempting this with this line:

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerUnit, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Input, UInt32(trackIndex), volume, 0)
```

The problem is that adjusting `trackIndex` 0 adjusts *every input* coming into the mixer, not just the one bus like I'm expecting it to.

Here is the output from `CAShow` of the master graph

```
AudioUnitGraph 0xC590003:
  Member Nodes:
    node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x60000002d580 O I
    node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x60000002d680 O I
    node 3: 'aumu' 'msyn' 'appl', instance 0x60000002db60 O I
    node 4: 'aumu' 'msyn' 'appl', instance 0x60000002ef20 O I
    node 5: 'aumu' 'msyn' 'appl', instance 0x60000002df00 O I
    node 6: 'aumu' 'msyn' 'appl', instance 0x60800022d820 O I
  Connections:
    node   2 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   3 bus   0 => node   2 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   4 bus   0 => node   2 bus   1  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   5 bus   0 => node   2 bus   2  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   6 bus   0 => node   2 bus   3  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
  CurrentState:
    mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isInitialized=T, isRunning=T (2)
```

Here is the class I wrote to control all of this: https://gist.github.com/jadar/26d9625c875ce91dd2ad0ad63dfd8f80

Comment: The only place I see you using kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume in your class is with kAudioUnitScope_Input. In addition to setting each sampler's volume to the mixer, you can set the mixer's output as a whole by using kAudioUnitScope_Output.

Answer (score 0):

Mixers are difficult because in a way the channels break the audio stream paradigm that core audio sets up, plus its different for the crosspoints than the input/output masters, and different for the global master.

Based on the code you provided, and assuming you're passing 0 for `trackIndex`, I would look at the volumes by using the property `kAudioUnitProperty_MatrixLevels` (which can be tricky to use, so let me know if you need help with that). It's possible that the crosspoint levels are not set correctly and that lowering `trackIndex` 0 (which is actually bus 0 channel 0) it's affecting everything you hear.

In case it's not clear, the way that the bus/channel paradigm works is it's a contiguous within the mixer itself. So if you have 4 busses with stereo channels and wanted to affect the right channel of bus 0, that would be mixer channel 7.